# Creating Blank Spaces for Letters in Randomly Selected Word

Tags: python

I'm a super-newbie Computing Science student, and I don't understand what the "blank answer = ''" statement does. My professor explained (I believe), that this will create a new space, but I'm not sure how this works. Thanks for reading the question!

```
correct_word = random.choice(['apple','banana','watermelon','kiwi','pineapple','mango'])
blank_answer = ' '

for character in correct_word:
    blank_answer = blank_answer + '_ '
```

Comment: `blank_answer` is a variable and you have set it equal to an empty space. The code you have written will add `' '` and `'_ '` because typing `blank_answer` is the same as typing `' '` once you've declared it to mean that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'm interpreting the code fragment is that your are building a set of underscores that when strung together create a blank line for printing on a page or other medium.

For instance let's say the choice was `apple`.  The variable blank_answer would be set to "_____" . One '_' for each letter in the work 'apple' so in this case five underscores.

For `watermelon` it would have 10 underscores "__________".  The loop effective adds an underscore for each letter in the selected word.

Comment: Thank-you for responding! I'm starting to piece together a little bit more of what this means; however, I do have a follow-up question. In the for loop, the word "character" is used - how does the Python interpreter know that I am referring to single letters, in the randomly chosen word?

Comment: Character is a variable name.  It has meaning to the author.  You could have used `c` `aChar` or `a`. The. Variable name is he authors choice.  If this answered your question please mark it so. Good luck in your learning

Comment: When iterating over a string (`for character in correct_word`) the variable (`character`) will take each of the string's character as value in each iteration.

Comment: So, is the variable name character, is special in a sense? The program will understand that I am trying to break down an object into it's characters?

Comment: Not really, it's just the variable name. It could be `for letter in correct_word` or `for x in correct_word` and would take the same effect

Comment: I am still a little confused - but thank you all so much for your help. As far as I understand, the random selection will return a string; for example "apple". When I state "for character in correct_word:", how come Python iterates the loop for each letter? I would assume it would treat "apple" as one object, and create one space. Hopefully that clarifies my question.

Comment: Strings are treated as arrays of characters, so when you do a for loop on a string, you are iterating through each character.

Comment: That makes perfect sense - thank you all! So, just a final clarification - a loop done on a single string, will have the iteration done on each letter.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already knew, but just in case, it's part of a hangman game. You want the user to correctly guess whatever random word is selected from the "correct_word" list. The rest of the game isn't shown, but essentially this program creates a blank space for the each letter in that word. Eventually it will replace the blank space with each letter that you guess correctly. Thus the user input.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33143126)